# What language is this?

Tags: languages

I took this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9GD1.jpg) while watching a BBC documentary. The scene showed a scientist keying into a computer. The language isn't something I've seen before. Does anybody know what it's?

Comment: While not an answer, a related site [moviecode.tumblr.com](http://moviecode.tumblr.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that is almost certainly [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) or [OCTAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave), the open-source version

Comment: Looks like the [Matlab IDE](http://blogs.mathworks.com/images/desktop/ken_orr_graphical_user_interfaces_are_just_plain_better/matlab_7_6.png) to me.